# Draw rectangles with Shape Digitizing Toolbar and using a snapping function in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I draw rectangles with the Shape Digitizing Toolbar. In QGIS 3 there is a Snapping Toolbar which provides a snapping function. But unfortunately it is not possible to use both together. So whenever I want to draw a rectangle I can not snap it onto a line which leads to incorrect results.

[Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137723/how-to-digitize-rectangles-with-snapping-in-qgis) is the same problem but it occured in QGIS 2.

Any solutions for QGIS 3?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you setup the settings in the snapping tool, but here is mine

[image]

- Enable snapping (red magnet icon)
- Snap to all layers, but you can select active layer
- Vertex and segment
- 10 pixels

Because I have the above settings, I can snap polygons together even to the one I have just created:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The problem is using the snapping tool TOGEHTER with the shape digitilizing tool ( tool to draw rectangles).